# Why I got console warning FancytreeNode@... scrollIntoView(): node is invisible?

Tags: jquery, fancytree

jquery.fancytree 2.31.0
jquery.fancytree.filter 2.31.0

I got console warning using filter: {mode: "dimm"}

FancytreeNode@... scrollIntoView(): node is invisible.

And when I changed the mode to filter: {mode: "hide"} and the search result would hide the fancytree element instead only hiding the unmatched nodes.

I am searching for an id of 5 and there a lot of pages with 15, 25, 35 and so on. All pages the parent pages having this page of 5's are

> FancytreeNode@44[title='44 - Our Services'] scrollIntoView(): node is invisible.

Comment: can you share you code